# Can make:controller command create nested controller class?

Tags: laravel-5.4

I am using laravel 5.4 to develop a project. I have a question about `php artisan make:controller` command. Can this command create a nested controller class, like `app/Http/Controllers/Admin/PostController` this? Or to do this I need to manually create this controller?

Comment: I think I found the answer. Just execute `php artisan make:controller Admin\PostController`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create create controllers in any controller namespace with the artisan command `php artisan make:controller Admin/ControllerName`

You can also create a resource controller by adding the `--resource` flag to the command.

You can go even further and typehint the model you wish to use with the controller by adding the `--model=ModelName` flag to the artisan command. If the model you have suggested does not exist, artisan will ask you if you would like to create this model.